# Mac script to copy files (execute by clicking on icon)

Tags: macos, command-line, shell

I have a script on my Mac Desktop:
`myProg.command` or `myProg.sh`,

the content is:

```
cp "foo/foo.txt" "bar/foo.txt"
```

The script is set as executable.
The directories `Desktop/foo`, `Desktop/bar` and the file `/Desktop/foo/foo.txt` exist.

But when I double click on the executable, I see the error messages
"command not found" and "no such file or directory".

The output is:

```
Last login: Mon Nov 25 15:56:19 on ttys000
CompName:~ MyName$ /Users/MyName/Desktop/myProg.command ; exit;
cp: foo/foo.txt
No such file or directory
: command not found/myProg.command: line 2: 
: command not found/myProg.command: line 3: 
logout

[Process completed]
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: My guess would be that the script is run under a different directory - could you post the output of pwd? btw you know that task is trivial to do in Automator?

Comment: Well, for just 1 line of code I'd rather just use a script...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you launch a script  like that it is always started in your HOME folder.
This is NOT your Desktop folder.
The Desktop is a sub-folder of HOME.

You can tell from the prompt-string in your output-example: **"CompName:~ MyName$"** is the current folder into which executing of the script starts.

Comment: How do I change the HOME folder from inside the script? How should the script be modified so that it works?

Comment: @android_422 Huh ? You don't change the home-folder. You change the directory you are in with the cd command. "cd Desktop" as extra command before the copy. This is really basic stuff. You better Google for a basic Bash scripting course to get a little more background on this.

Answer (score 0):

I found where these error messages were coming from:

```
: command not found/myProg.command: line 2: 
: command not found/myProg.command: line 3:
```

My file was created on a Windows PC with `/r/n` for line break.
So apparently Mac was "thinking" the carriage return was a command.